# NSWindowController not hiding its window at init?

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

I have an NSDocument subclass with two NSWindowControllers corresponding to 2 different xib.

Following the Document-Based Application Guide I have added the following in my document.m implementation

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers 
{
    NSLog(@"in MakeWindowControllers");

    MainWindowController *mainWindowController = [[MainWindowController alloc] init];
    [mainWindowController autorelease];
    [self addWindowController:mainWindowController];

    csvWindowController = [[CSVWindowController alloc] init];
    [csvWindowController autorelease];
    [self addWindowController:csvWindowController];        
}
```

Problem is I want the second window controller csvWindowController to hide its window initially, I will show the same instance of the window later on. To do so I have written:

```
@implementation CSVWindowController


- (id) init {

    if ( ! (self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"CSVWindow"]) ) {

        NSLog(@"CSVWindowController init failed");
        return nil;
    }

    window = [self window];
    NSLog(@"CSVWindowController init");

    [window orderOut:nil]; // to hide it
    NSLog(@"CSVWindowController hiding the window");

    return self;
}
```

But the window is there, showing up.

Please not I have the VisibleAtLaunch not flagged, that console it's showing my messages correctly, and that even if I change:

```
        [window orderOut:nil]; // to hide it
to 
        [window orderOut:self]; // to hide it
```

The result is the same, window showing up.

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, again I reply to my own question, but this time with a positive remark. I think what I was doing wrong had something to do with the hidden - for me - implications of the Document-based architecture of the default Document Application template.

I have tried with a different approach, creating an application from scratch NOT flagging "Document-based Application" and providing it with:

- 1 NSDocument subclass
- 2 NSWindowControllers subclasses
- 1 MainMenu.xib
- 2 window.xib

and I have forced instantiation of the NSWindowController subclasses in the MyDocument code.

I have also put the IBActions for the MenuItems in the MyDocument and I have bound the MyDocument Object to the MenuItems in the MainMenu.xib.

**This time I was able to do whatever, hiding/showing windows starting with one hidden one not, enabling menu items automatically at will.**

Here follows the code, for any newbie like me who might have to fight with this in the future.

```
//  MyDocument.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "testWindowController.h"
#import "test2WindowController.h"

@interface MyDocument : NSDocument {
    testWindowController *test;
    test2WindowController *test2;

}

- (IBAction)showWindow1:(id)pId;
- (IBAction)showWindow2:(id)pId;
- (IBAction)hideWindow1:(id)pId;
- (IBAction)hideWindow2:(id)pId;

@end


//  MyDocument.m
#import "MyDocument.h"
#import "testWindowController.h"
#import "test2WindowController.h"

@implementation MyDocument

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        NSLog(@"MyDocument init...");
        [self makeWindowControllers];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)makeWindowControllers 
{

    test = [[testWindowController alloc] init];
    test2 = [[test2WindowController alloc] init];  

    [self addWindowController:test];
    [self addWindowController:test2];

    // start hiding the first window
    [[test window] orderOut:self];
}

- (IBAction)hideWindow1:(id)pId
{
    NSLog(@"hideWindow1");
    [[test window] orderOut:self];
}

- (IBAction)showWindow1:(id)pId
{
    NSLog(@"showWindow1");
    [test showWindow:self];
    [[test window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]; // to show it
}

- (IBAction)hideWindow2:(id)pId
{
    NSLog(@"hideWindow2");
    [[test2 window] orderOut:self];
}

- (IBAction)showWindow2:(id)pId
{
    NSLog(@"showWindow2");
    [test2 showWindow:self];
    [[test2 window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]; // to show it
}


 -(BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem {

     NSLog(@"in validateMenuItem for item: %@", [menuItem title]);

     if ([[menuItem title] isEqualToString:@"Show Window"] 
         && [[test window] isVisible]){
         return NO;
     }

     if ([[menuItem title] isEqualToString:@"Hide Window"] 
         && ![[test window] isVisible]){
         return NO;
     }

     if ([[menuItem title] isEqualToString:@"Show Window2"] 
         && [[test2 window] isVisible]){
         return NO;
     }

     if ([[menuItem title] isEqualToString:@"Hide Window2"] 
         && ![[test2 window] isVisible]){
         return NO;
     }
     return [super validateMenuItem:menuItem];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another method to prevent NSDocument's window(s) to show up early:

- Subclass NSDocuments's window in IB
- Use a flag to signal when window content is ready
- Override makeKeyAndOrderFront method.

```
@interface DocWindow : NSWindow

@property BOOL inited;

@end

@implementation DocWindow

- (void)makeKeyAndOrderFront:(id)sender
{
    if ( _inited )
        [super makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}

@end

@implementation Document

- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)windowController
{
    // prepare window content here.
    ...

    // show doc's window when ready
    DocWindow *win = (DocWindow *)self.window;
    win.inited = YES;
    [win makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

@end
```